# Import a large dataset into SAS using proc import

Tags: sas

I'm importing an .xlsx file into SAS using the following code:

```
proc import 
    out = in_oid_compliance
    datafile = "&data_home\raw\03. OI Drug Compliance and Ovulation Tracking Form\03_OICompliance.xlsx"
    dbms = excel replace;
run;
```

The excel file has one worksheet called `OID`, and this code works fine. However, I've jsut discovered that `dbms = excel` only imports the first 255 columns, and my dataset has c.400. If I change to the following code:

```
proc import 
    out = in_oid_compliance
    datafile = "&data_home\raw\LOCI 03. OI Drug Compliance and Ovulation Tracking Form\Loci_03_OICompliance.xlsx"
    dbms = xlsx replace;
run;
```

I get the following error:

```
No worksheets in the .XLSX file
Requested Input File Is Invalid
ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
```

My question is - what am I doing wrong? Or, is there another way of importing a large excel file into SAS?

Answer (score 1):

`Proc IMPORT` can fail if the `datafile=` specifies a direct filename that is more than 200 characters.

Use a FILENAME statement to reference the longly named file, and the fileref in the datafile= option.

```
filename cpl "... very long filename that might also involve macro variables ...";
proc import datafile=cpl ...
...
```

Comment: Helpful.  But that normally gives a different error message.   `ERROR: File Name value exceeds maximum length of 201 characters.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok - this is the answer:

I had to enable editing on the excel file and it works fine now. For some reason I don't need it is using `dbms = excel`.

Comment: DBMS=EXCEL uses Microsoft software tools to actually extract the data.  Sounds like whatever settings was making the original file prevent editing was what was making the XLSX engine not recognize the file.  Perhaps the file wasn't even an XLSX file at all but just something that the Microsoft tools could understand, like perhaps the older XLS format file.